# How do I divide values that are in the same column based on an ID column and Project Column?

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to create a column on a Power BI table that divides values from one column based on an ID column which IDs that I specify and particular Project I am assigning it to.

I understand that I need to loop through the column twice but I am kind of confused about how to do that. I have used the function `LOOKUPVALUE` but I keep getting an error. Below is the code that I am working on:

```
Answer =
VAR LookupID =
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        Table[ID] IN { 11, 31, 51 }, 1,
        Table[ID] IN { 12, 32, 52 }, 2,
        Table[ID] IN { 13, 33, 53 }, 3
    )
RETURN
    Calculate(Table[Q] / LOOKUPVALUE ( Table[Q], Table[ID], LookupID ),Allexcept(Table, Table[Project]))
```

Below is a demonstration on what I want to accomplish
[image]

Error that I keep getting:
[image]

Comment: What's the error? Also, are you trying to do a calculated column or a measure?

Comment: "A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected". Thank you for answering my previous question. This lead to a new problem because I have multiple projects tied to these ID numbers. So there are multiple rows with the same ID names that are in different projects

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use that DAX code as a measure instead of a calculated column. You don't have row context in a measure, so it would need to be rewritten since e.g. `Table[Q]` is a column rather than a single value.

Comment: It is a calculated Column. I believe the single value Table[Q] is being divided by a column of numbers with the lookupvalue function. If you delete the lookupvalue function it works because its just quantities being displayed and not the formula

Comment: Is there a way to filter by "project" in the "lookupvalue" function? "lookupvalue" is causing the error

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a calculated column, try this as your last line:

```
Table[Q] / LOOKUPVALUE ( Table[Q], Table[ID], LookupID, Table[Project], Table[Project] )
```

You can have as many column/value pairs in a lookup as you'd like. This tells it to match on `Project` as well.

---

Note: When you use `CALCULATE`, it performs a context transition that turns your row context into filter context and you have to use aggregations (as you do with measures) instead of raw column values like you can normally do in a calculated column row context.

Comment: I added the error that I am receiving inside the question ^. It contains code that does not follow the example. It relates to the document I am currently working on but it doing the same thing.

Comment: Does wrapping the last `Table[Project]` with `EARLIER` help: `EARLIER(Table[Project])`? If not, how about hardcoding that last argument with `1.0`?